# Why do we have a link to some bizarre chat room on the main page of tex.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, status-completed, chat, hyperlinks

On the main page of tex.stackexchange.com right now is a link to a chat room:

> In which the relative merits of Word and LaTeX are discussed.

I don't like to see that there.  I think that TeX-SX has stayed fairly civil on the relative merits of different systems: our task is to sing the praises of TeX, not to be nasty about other stuff.  The etiquette that I've seen so far has been along the lines of: "Of course we think that TeX is the best thing since sliced bread, didn't you read the sign on the door?  But if you're nice to us, we'll be nice to you and we'll show you the error of your ways by example, not by preaching.".

What I've read so far of that discussion does not follow that etiquette.  Indeed, what I've read so far is a pretty pointless discussion.  Moreover, the room seems to be closed so no new discussion can take place, and it doesn't seem to have been started by or involve anyone from the TeX-SX site.

So why is it linked from our main page as if it were anything to do with or endorsed by us?

Please remove it!

Comment: Cross-post; I've already answered the [original](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1122/why-do-we-have-a-link-to-some-bizarre-chat-room-on-the-main-page)

Comment: Here's the room Andrew have in mind: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/176

Comment: Incidentally, I brutally ignore downvotes that aren't accompanied by explanation.

Comment: @balpha I'm deleting the room, please tell me when frozen rooms are no longer advertised so I can undelete it.

Comment: [status-completed] for the "frozen room being advertised" thing

Comment: Why in the world is this downvoted three times? I'd be less than thrilled if "Discuss the vast superiority of Windows" suddenly appeared in the UL room list

Comment: @Michael That doesn't change the fact your users can start such a room at any time.

Comment: @badp No, but if I then asked about it on meta I wouldn't except a sudden flurry of downvotes; it was a completely reasonable question

Answer (score 3):

It was a discussion about TeX and LaTeX (and Word), so I reassigned it after the fact to TeX and LaTeX, rather than Gaming, on grounds of topicality. I agree it was unpleasant, but that's no ground for "censorship."

(I did ask for reassignment during the chatting itself, but my moderator flag has been ignored.)

Since the room is frozen, it'll fade away soon enough. Chat more to make it go away :)

---

Oh, additionally. Site policy does not need apply to chat. Bad subjective content, such as polls, asking for opinion or just relaxed exchange of ideas is fine there. It also is unenforceable, because there's no way of preventing somebody from taking part into TeX chatrooms and TeX chatrooms alone, short of a chat.stackexchange-wide chat ban. That would be inappropriate.

Comment: I have no wish to **censor** it.  It is its presence on the main page which to someone unfamiliar with the inner workings of the SE empire (such as myself) might look like endorsement or "here's a site we think you should look at".  Neither of which is the case.

Comment: By "chat more", do you mean that we should have more chat rooms?  Activity in our main room presumably wouldn't bump it off the page.  (Nonetheless, there are a couple of other rooms, I'll go and chat there to get rid of the offending room)

Comment: Okay, I've put chat messages in other rooms, a whole new room has been opened and briefly appeared on the main page, but the offending room appears to resurface again and again, like that annoying tune you heard in the store at the weekend and can't get out of your head!

Comment: @Andrew I'll now delete the room; I'll undelete it when balpha confirms frozen rooms are no longer advertised.

Comment: That's the case already